# How do I get the correct degress from style.transform rotate after I converted the matrix values?

Tags: javascript, html, math, rotation, degrees

I am trying to get the rotation degree from div's I rotate to create a line pattern.

Only now I am running into a problem. I need the rotation(deg) from the div's to calculate where the next line needs to appear. But when I try to get the value from a div with style.transform and convert the matrix values I still get the wrong degrees.

In my testing case I have a div that is rotated 150deg, but I get 30 deg back and this will not work for me unfortunatly. Please help, how do I get the 150deg value back?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="linesBox" id="linesBox">
    <div class="line1 lines" id="line1" style="float: left;
    margin: 200px 0 0 100px;
    position: fixed;
    border-top:0.5px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    transform: rotate(150deg);"></div> 
    <!-- <div class="line2 lines" id="line1" style="float: left;
    margin: 174px 0 0 193.3px;
    position: fixed;
    border-top:0.5px solid black;
    width:100px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);"></div> -->



</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const linesBox = document.getElementById('linesBox');

let lastLineWidth;
let angle;
let lineWidthCount;
let lineHeightCount;

function createLines(){

//Last line div in a var and a var to get the computated value 
let lastLine = linesBox.lastElementChild;
var st = window.getComputedStyle(lastLine, null);

//Get the width and angle of the last line and place them in a var
lastLineWidth = parseFloat(lastLine.style.width);
lastLineXPos = parseFloat(lastLine.style.marginLeft);
lastLineYPos = parseFloat(lastLine.style.marginTop);
let lastLineAngle = st.getPropertyValue("transform");
console.log(lastLineWidth, lastLineXPos, lastLineYPos);

//Get and map the Matrix value from transform rotate() and set it to lastLineAngle
var values = lastLineAngle.split('(')[1],
    values = values.split(')')[0],
    values = values.split(',');

//Set each value of the matrix values to a var
let a = values[0]; 
let b = values[1]; 
let c = values[2];
let d = values[3]; 

//Take the correc value from the matrix values and place it in the formula and save the outcome in a var
angle = Math.round(Math.asin(b) * (180/Math.PI));
console.log(angle);

//Calculate margin left starting position for the next line
//Get sin en cos values by angle 
let yChangeOne = lastLineWidth * Math.sin(angle / 180 * Math.PI) / 2;
let xChangeOne = parseFloat(lastLineWidth - lastLineWidth * Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI)) / 2;


// let yChangeOne = lastLineWidth * sinOutcome / 2;
// let xChangeOne = lastLineWidth - lastLineWidth * cosOutcome; 
console.log(yChangeOne, xChangeOne);

let newYPos;
let newXPos;

if( angle <= 89 && angle >= 1 ){
    newYPos = lastLineYPos + yChangeOne;

} else if ( angle >= 91 && angle <= 179 ){
    newYPos = lastLineYPos - yChangeOne;
}
console.log(newYPos);} 

  //Get the start position for the next line  
  createLines();
```

The angle should return 150deg not 30deg otherwise my if statement will not work. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 30° and 150° have the same sine. You also need to take the cosine into account. Instead of `Math.asin(b)`, use

```
Math.atan2(b, a)
```

Btw, if you are just calculating the angle to calculate its sine and cosine again, then spare this step (`Math.sin(angle...))`. You have sine and cosine right there, so just use them.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Only one small problem left. When the degree goes over 180deg, I get minum values and my code doesnt work anymore. I can work around this, but for my case it would be best if I can get the value of the full 360deg, so if you have a solution for that its more then welcome :)

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for angles greater than 180°? You might get a negative angle, but since you are using only its sine and cosine anyway, there should be no difference.

Comment: I use the real angle for my if statement. I need the full 360 degree for this to work. Also with a negative value not everything return as value so my code is not working anymore

Comment: P.s. later on in the code I also need the angle prefferably with full 360 degree count

Comment: `if(angle < 0) angle += 360;`